# Is $\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ periodic?with what period time?

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

Is $\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$
periodic? with what period time?

Comment: no it is not periodic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not. If it *were* periodic, the derivative would be periodic too (I'll let you prove this result). But here,
$$f'(x)=\frac{-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^2}\to 0 \ \text{ as } \ x \to\infty, $$

and so, it's impossible that $x\mapsto \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is periodic.