# Find period of $y=\sin\frac1x$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find period of $$y=\sin\frac1x$$

We knew that function $y=\sin x$ has period $2\pi$, $y=\sin2x$ has period $\pi$. And $y=\sin \frac1x$ has period $2\pi$, but when I see its graph, I think I was wrong.

> If anyone feels this question isn't necessary, I will delete it.

Comment: It's not periodic. The definition of periodic function states that f(x) has period a iff $f(x+a)=f(x)\,\,\forall x$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949291/is-sin1-x-periodicwith-what-period-time

Comment: Can't be periodic because at neighborhood of zero must take all the values of [-1,1] infinitely many times.

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee But $\sin\left(\frac1x+2\pi\right)=\sin \frac1x$

Comment: If $f(x)=\sin\frac{1}{x}$, then $f(x+2\pi)=\sin\frac{1}{x+2\pi}$ and not $\sin\Bigl(\frac{1}{x}+2\pi\Bigr)$

Comment: @DDK, If $$f(x)=\sin\dfrac1x,f(x+2n\pi)=\sin\dfrac1{x+2n\pi}\ne\sin\dfrac1x$$ in general

Comment: Yes, $\sin(\frac1x+2\pi)=\sin(\frac1x)$. That doesn't say it's periodic. Say $f(x)=\sin(\frac1x)$. Then $f(x+2\pi)=\sin(\frac1{x+2\pi})\ne\sin(\frac1x+2\pi)$.

Comment: Thanks everyone. If anyone feels this question isn't necessary, I will close it. :)

Comment: I hate to be the rebel here, but clearly, the function does oscillate, and we could say that it has a variable period/frequency. So my answer is $$\sin\frac{1}{x} =\sin \frac{1}{x^2}x$$ which implies that the period is $2\pi x^2$

Answer (score 3):

No it's not periodic. However, let's assume it were.

If $y=\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is periodic so is it's derivative is periodic, which is not true. Therefore it is not periodic and it doesn't have a period.

Also you can clearly see it is not periodic from it's plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The plot of the function actually looks like that: g
[image]