# Prove that $f(x) = \cos(1/x)$ is not periodic without using calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Given a function $$f(x)=\cos\frac{1}{x}$$ Prove that it  is not periodic.

I've started with assuming that $f(x)$ is periodic and hence $f(x) = f(x+2\pi)$ since $\cos$ hat period $T = 2\pi$. This gives:

$$
\cos\frac{1}{x} = \cos\frac{1}{x+2\pi}
$$

Given the above we may take some value x and check whether the equation holds for that value. Let's say $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, then
$$
\cos\frac{2}{\pi} = \cos\frac{2}{5\pi}
$$
which is not true. Hence $f(x) = \cos\frac{1}{x}$ is not periodic. I've found similar questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413767/find-period-of-y-sin-frac1x) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949291/is-sin1-x-periodicwith-what-period-time) but they use derivatives for the proof.

> Can I somehow prove the above in a general way without taking any exact value for $x$ and without using calculus?

Comment: How do you prove whether a function is periodic or not, using derivatives?

Comment: There's quite a few ways. One would be by showing that $\lim_{x\to\infty} cos\frac 1 x$ exists

Comment: @Batominovski if a function is continuous and periodic then its derivative is also periodic, isn't that true?

Comment: But the periodicity of the derivative does not imply the periodicity of the original function.

Comment: @Batominovski I've just found [this proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Periodic_Function)

Comment: That is not what I asked for.  The function $f(x)=x$ is not periodic, but its derivative is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $$\cos\frac1x=\cos\frac1{x+T}.$$

Then we must have

$$\frac1x=\pm\frac1{x+T}+2k\pi,
$$

$$k=\frac{\dfrac1x\mp\dfrac1{x+T}}{2\pi}.$$

But the RHS cannot be an integer for all $x$, a contradiction.

Comment: that is beautiful

Comment: Can you please explain why "the RHS cannot be an integer for all $x$."?

Comment: @yakobyd It's a continuous function of $x$. This arguably uses "calculus", but it's also intuitively obvious. Alternatively, it's a non integer for sufficiently large $x$ since the numerator tends to $0$. For example, plug in $x=10^{100}$.

Comment: Ohh, now I can see what I have missed. I thought that it says that for every $x$, $k$ is not an integer (what a rookie mistake in logic). Thank you for your explanation @JackM.

Comment: @JackM: indeed, for $x>1/\pi$, $0<k<1$ !

Answer (score 3):

The zeros of $f$ are at the points $x$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi
$$
for $k$ a positive integer. Then they are of the form
$$
x=\frac{2}{(2k+1)\pi}<\frac{2}{\pi}
$$
Since the set of zeros is nonempty and bounded, the function cannot be periodic, because if $T>0$ is a period and $x_0$ is a zero, then also $x_0+nT$ would be a zero, for every positive integer $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Let us proove the following theorem

> **Theorem:** Assume $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ has a minimal period $T\in\mathbb{R}$, that
>   is, for all $x\in \mathbb{R} : f(x+T) = f(x)$. Then
>   $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ does not exist.

**Proof:** $T$ is minimal, thus,  there is some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0) \ne f(x_0 + \frac12T)$. Choose the sequence $t_n = x_0 + \frac12nT$. We have that

$$  f(t_n) = 
  \begin{cases} 
   f(x_0) & \text{if } n \text{ is even} \\
   f(x_0+\frac12 T)       & \text{if } n \text{ is odd}
  \end{cases} $$

and  since $f(x_0) \ne f(x_0 + \frac12T)$ we get that the sequence $f(t_n)$ diverges when $n\to\infty$. From here we conclude that the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ does not exist.

Now, regarding your question we have that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \cos\left(\frac1x\right) = \lim_{x\to0} \cos(x) = 1$ (by continuity of $\cos(x)$ at $x=0$), that is, the limit exists. Thus by the theorem above we conclude that $\cos\left(\frac1x \right) $ has no minimal period.

This can mean two things: either it has no period or it has infinitly many periods with no minimum. If it is the former case we are done. Hence, assume the latter. Continuous functions that have infinitely many periods with no minimum are constatnt (a nice exercise). Our function is continuous and is not constant and thus we reached a contradiction.

In total we have shown that $\cos\left(\frac1x \right)$ has no period. Perhaps this method is too long for this particular question, but assuming the rigorous background behind it is known, this trick can come pretty handy. (This answer was heavily influenced by @Sudix 's comment).

Answer (score 1):

There is a non-calculus proof of the inequality $\cos(t)\geq 1-\frac{t^2}{2}$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.  I am not providing a proof of this inequality.

Suppose on the contrary that $T>0$ is *a* period of $f$.  Choose an integer $n>0$ such that $nT>1$.  Then, we have that $0<f(nT)<1$.  Let $N>0$ be an integer so large that that $NT> \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\big(1-f(nT)\big)}}$.  Then, $f(NT)>f(nT)$, which is a contradiction.

However, surely, there are easier ways.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach does not work: who's to say that $f$ has period $2\pi$, just because cosine does?

You can of course assume $f$ has some unknown period $T>0$, and try to derive a contradiction. You would need
$$\cos\frac{1}{x} = \cos\frac{1}{x+nT}$$
for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. It's not hard to use elementary properties of cosine to prove this: for example, if assuming that cosine is strictly decreasing between $0$ and $\pi$ does not "count as calculus," try $x=1/\pi$ and $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

For $x>\frac2\pi$ we have $0 < \frac1x<\frac\pi2$ and hence  $f(x)=\cos\frac 1x>0$, whereas $f(\frac1{\pi})=\cos\pi=-1$. If $T>0$ is a period of $f$, pick $n\in\Bbb N$ with $nT>\frac2\pi$ and arrive at the contradiction $-1=f(\frac1\pi)=f(\frac1\pi+nT)>0$.